# Can we load images from image URLs directly to CNN models in Keras/TensorFlow without storing the images in a local directory?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I want to retrieve Images from Image URLs and feed them into CNN model in keras but I do not want to store the images in the local folder ?

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `skimage` to read an image from a image URL like this

```
from skimage import io
import cv2

# Read image from web image
image = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/QupKb.png')

# Display image
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Got it. But If I want to load into Model directly ? so I am storing image URLs in a dataframe and want to use Imagedatagenerator.flow from dataframe ? something like that possible ?

Comment: @DebayanMitra you should open a new question for that, im sure its possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use skimage.io to reading images from URLs. After reading you should expand the array. Ex: image array shape is (64,64,3). After expanding (1,64,64,3)

```
from skimage import io
import tensorflow as tf

#Load model
model = tf.load_model("model.h5")

# Read image from web image
image_array = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/QupKb.png')

img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) 
predictions = model.predict(img_array)
```